# circularly symmetric Gaussian variables using matlab

Tags: random, matrix, statistics, gaussian, normal-distribution

any one can help me, i want to generate a matrix with elements being zero mean and unit variance independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) circularly symmetric Gaussian variables using Matlab any one know the code for this and how to do it

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to generate a matrix with elements being zero mean and unit variance by using this command in matlab:

```
normrnd(mu, sigma)
```

- `mu` is the mean
- `sigma` is the standard deviation.

More detail please `help normrnd` in MATLAB.