# Create a zero mean complex gaussian,but its mean and pseudocovariance are not zero

Tags: matlab

I use matlab to create zero mean circularly symmetric complex gaussian according to this website:  [circularly symmetric Gaussian variables using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089934/circularly-symmetric-gaussian-variables-using-matlab)

However,when i  verify whether it is  zero mean circularly symmetric complex gaussian or not,i found that the mean and pseudocovariance of gaussian i create is not zero,so i want to ask where am i wrong ?

My code

```
%zero mean circularly symmetric complex gaussian
L=5
h_1=normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])+1i*normrnd( 0,sqrt(0.1*(L^(-2.5))) ,[4,1])

%Verify whether the mean is zero or not
expected_value=mean(h_1)

%Verify whether the pseudocovariance is zero or not
pseudocovariance=mean(h_1'*h_1)

%Verify whether the cov( e^{jk} * h_1) is equal to cov( h_1) or not
origi = cov(h_1)
origi_expon=cov(exp(1i*4)*h_1)
differ=origi-origi_expon
```

My zero mean circularly symmetric complex gaussian is a 4 by 1 matrix

In this slides:https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/~sarva/courses/EE703/2013/Slides/CircularlySymmetricGaussian.pdf

He said the zero mean circularly symmetric complex gaussian has to satisfy three things,mean and pseudocovariance have to be zero,and cov( e^{jk} * h_1) is equal to cov( h_1),so i write the code as he said whether my code is right or not

Comment: `h_1'*h_1` computes the sum of the square magnitudes (this is a dot product). The mean of that sum is the sum. Instead of calling `mean`, divide this sum by `numel(h_1)`. — Also, you will have to average way more than 4 values to see it the mean is zero.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i had verified the sum problem you said,but the value  the mean of that sum and the "mean" i use are both the same

Comment: @CrisLuengo So briefly you think h_1 is zero mean circularly symmetric complex gaussian ,but my verification method is not correct?

Comment: Are you saying that `h_1'*h_1/4 == mean(h_1'*h_1)`??? I don’t believe that! Otherwise, yes, you need to generate a million random numbers to see that their mean is close to zero. It will never be exactly zero. You are drawing random numbers from a distribution with zero mean, this does not mean that the average of those random numbers will be zero.

Comment: of course not,i  mean we sum all h_1 ,and average them,this value will be equal to the value that we use mean instruction directly.However,according to the slide i provided,he said both mean and pseudocovariance of zero mean circularly symmetric complex gaussian have to be zero